# Wrong/weird characters when I fetch friend list through facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$friends = $friends_list['data'];
$fco = count($friends_list['data']);
$output = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $fco; $i++)
{
 $output .= $friends[$i]['name'] . " - " . $friends[$i]['id'];
}
```

When I use this code I get weird charecters. Such as `Ã¼` this for `ü`

If I use `utf8_decode($output)`, then everything seems fine except I/ı and Ğ/ğ turns into "?" (yep question mark)

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

tell the browser what encoding you're sending

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

> cant post here due to the fact that opera and stackoverflow doesnt work well for some reason.

What? Works perfectly fine for me …

> How do I fix it ?

Fix your application/site, by converting it to use UTF-8 (or Unicode in general) for storage and displaying of data –

> If I use utf8_decode($output), then everything seems fine except I/ı and Ğ/ğ turns into "?"(yep question mark)

– instead of *destroying* the data partially by converting it to ISO-8859-1.

ISO-8859-1 does *not contain* characters like I/ı and Ğ/ğ – that’s why you’re just getting question marks in their place.